# OTRS doesn't start on apache2

Tags: bash, ubuntu, apache2, otrs

I'm setting up **otrs** server on **apache2**, but when I start up apache2 service I just get default apache2 page even though I already configured **otrs.conf** in **/sites-avaible/** This is following steps I took:

```
ln -s /opt/otrs/scripts/apache2-httpd.include.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/otrs.conf
a2ensite otrs.conf
service apache2 reload
```

[Console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LViF3.jpg)

Comment: disable default site: `a2dissite 000-default.conf`double check your config at `otrs.conf`

Comment: thank you that was almost right, I had to also dissite otrs.conf and ensite it again then it worked

Comment: I'm glad it worked @dangaus jonas

Answer (score 0):

disable default site: **a2dissite 000-default**.confdouble check your config at otrs.conf – LasVegasCoder

also had to add few commands

```
a2dissite 000-default
a2dissite otrs.conf
service apache2 reload
a2ensite otrs.conf
service apache2 reload
```